# How do I get VSCode to recognize Python3 as my default

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pyspark

I have python3 install on my Mac and I'm in the terminal, I use python3 by default. However when I'm in VSCode it is not recognizing python3 as my default, it's still pulling in python2.7.

Here is a screenshot of my VScode environement:
I have code-runner with python3 selected as well as my interpreter as 3.8

[image]

When I run my code, I get this annoying error:

```
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.8, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

I have to call `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` to get my code to run, but I've already got that built in my bash.profile.

What am I missing in order to get this to run properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in `settings.json` and reload the window to make the setting work:

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "\path to python3\",
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear why you're exporting things unless you are running code from the terminal window. Your terminal is not connected to the vscode settings.

You need to run scripts actually from vscode if you want that environment to be applied

Comment: I wanted to match all environments correctly. I can run the react code from terminal in VS code just fine. But I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Well, if the terminal is not picking up the other settings, there's nothing to "match" against

Answer (score 0):

**First Check** Please import you packages through the
".py" files in vs code and check again if it works. If it still doesn't work then follow the steps below.

**Method 1:** Please check your environment on vs code; if it is set to the python version you intend to use. This problem could be because your environment on vs code is set a a python version which you don't want to use, henceforth you can follow the method mentioned earlier in order to fix the error.

**Method 2:** If this doesn't work change you python interpreter through command palette (this will be accessible only when a python file is opened or a folder containing python files).

**IMPORTANT:** In order for the second method to work, you'll need to download this extension in vs code, only then you can change your interpreter.

**Link:**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance